# Change UITextField's placeholder text color using Userattributes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to change Place holder color from user attributes (interface builder) because i dont want to subclass my UITextfield etc... i searched on internet and found this "_placeholderLabel.textColor" Yes this works well Programmatically     `[self.tfEmail setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];` but i want to use it in user attributes in interface builder.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try removing '_',

[image]

Works for me.

Comment: Lol I have never someone chance the placeholder like that in interface builder! aha awesome, i wonder what else you can create using that same method

Comment: simply awesome..!! Great buddy.

Comment: You can change Font you can change any property that exists. No need to do it programatically.

Comment: @Xeieshan, will it be for UITextField only or any control?

Comment: Can do it on any control :)

Comment: Make any Control yourself and change its property from user attributes in Identity Inspector.

Comment: Both of you http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=395 http://blog.gaeremynck.com/user-defined-runtime-attributes-in-ios/ for your Knowledge.

Comment: LoL .. Awesome :)

Answer (score 4):

**Without USING USER ATTRIBUTES**

```
 self.txtField.attributedPlaceholder = PlaceHolderAttributedString(@"ABCDEF");
```

where PlaceHolderAttributedString is a macro defined as

```
 #define PlaceHolderAttributedString(placeHolderText) [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeHolderText attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:ColorTextFieldPlaceHolder}]
```

**USING USER ATTRIBUTES**

```
 placeholderLabel.textColor
```

Answer (score 0):

in swift:

```
    one_textfield.setValue(UIColor.redColor(), forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
```